# Entropy change for molecular nitrogen

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Calculate specific entropy change for $N_2$ from 250 K and 1000 kPa to 1300 K and 60 kPa using $\Delta s=\phi_2-\phi_1-R\ln (\frac{p_2}{p_1})$ given that $\phi_1=6.6587\ kJ/kg/K$ and $\phi_2=8.4604\ kJ/kg/K$.

My question is what the physical meaning of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ is.

Answer (score 0):

In this notation, $\phi$ is the temperature part of the entropy, while the last term in the equation is the pressure part.

Answer (score 0):

Since $s$ is a thermodynamic variable, we can write its differential as follows:
\begin{equation}
ds = \left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial T}\right)_{P}dT + \left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial P}\right)_{T}dP\ ,
\end{equation}
where the subindices denote the variable that remains fixed. In addition, we know that the specific heat associated to the thermodynamic variable $x$ can be written in terms of the specific entropy,
\begin{equation}
c_{x} = T\left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial T}\right)_{x}\ .
\end{equation}
Thus, the differential can be expressed as follows
\begin{equation}
ds = \frac{c_{P}}{T}dT + \left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial P}\right)_{T}dP\ .
\end{equation}
Since the integrations can be carried out separately, it should be possible to make the following identifications:

\begin{align}
\phi_{2}-\phi_{1}& = \int^{T_{2}}_{T_{1}}\frac{c_{P}}{T}dT\\
-R\ln\left(\frac{P_{2}}{P_{1}}\right)& = \int^{P_{2}}_{P_{1}}\left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial P}\right)_{T}dP\ .
\end{align}

Therefore, the physical meaning of the first term is related to the change in temperature of the specific entropy, as it was pointed out before.

Answer (score -1):

$ \Delta\phi = \int_1^2 \frac{c_p}{T}dT $

Comment: I see, $\phi_1$ is integrated from $T_0$ to $T_1$ where $T_0$ is an arbitrary reference, in this case taken to be $kelvin / e$ or about $0.3678\ K$. It will cancel out in the delta but it's close enough to absolute zero for $\phi_1$ to be a measure of total internal heat content. Does that make sense?

Comment: I do not fully understand your comment but as you stated the lower reference limit $T_0$ is arbitrary for $\phi$ because we take only the difference and the lower limit is the same for both, so the integral depends only on the $T_1$ and $T_2$ values and not on an arbitrary reference temperature. This of course is the same in general for all entropy calculations because in macroscopic thermodynamics we only care about entropy changes. I hope this answers *your question*.